# Retrieve database record + another option value using options_for_select in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am studying creating a form on Ruby on Rails but I cannot seem to know how to return the values I wanted using options_for_select.

I wanted to retrieve all position numbers + add 1 to the last number as a select option every time a user creates a new "subject".

e.g. user creates a new Subject
in the Form field, Position. The options will be 1,2,3(numbers retrieve in the database) and 4(being the new number not yet in the database)

I successfully tried retrieving the database values and the "other" value separately but I could not join them to return together in the same option field.

However, I can add them together but the instance variables are manually added one by one.

Here's the code…
In views and controller

```
<%= f.select(:position, options_for_select([@position, @positionTwo.position, @position.last, @additional])) %>

@position = Subject.pluck(:position)
@positionTwo = Subject.find(2)
@additional = Subject.pluck(:position).size + 1
```

generates
options 1,2,3,4 but results are added manually

I successfully tried retrieving the database values using:

```
<%= f.select(:position, options_for_select(@position)) %>
@position = Subject.pluck(:position)
```

this generates options 1,2,3

for the "other" value

```
<%= f.select(:position, options_for_select(@additional)) %>
@additional = Subject.pluck(:position).size + 1
```

it generates option 4

**What my expected behavior and result should be**

options 1,2,3,4 generated dynamically

the 1,2,3 is retrieve from the database while 4 is a dynamic number depending on the last position number in the database+1 (3+1 = 4)

Answer (score 1):

If I get the point, fetching from Subject as `@position = Subject.pluck(:position)` you end up, for example, with:

```
@position = [1,2,3]
```

Then you need to append one element which value is the last incremented by one.

For Ruby 2.6 you could try using [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-then):

```
[1,2,3].then { |ary| ary << ary.last + 1 } #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, in your case this should work:

```
@position = Subject.pluck(:position).then { |positions| positions << positions.last + 1 }
```

For Ruby 2.5 use [Object#yield_self](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.5/Object.html#method-i-yield_self).

Comment: I kinda like the lambda alternative. But still I am grateful for the help!

Although the code has an error, it says undefined method `then' ...

Comment: Probably because you are not running Ruby 2.6. For 2.5 use yield_self. Does the same.

Comment: Yes the yield_self is working… However, I just notice that .size is better than .last since users could choose a duplicate/same position. 

When using .last
e.g instead of the last position, 4, users can choose 1. so outcome will be [1,2,3,1(4 before),2)

using .size
output is [1,2,3,1,5]

Comment: but still it's not 100% what I wanted… output should still be [1,2,3,4(the new number)] since there is a duplicate for position 1. I guess the solution is to prevent users from choosing position and just use the last position then. Thanks!

Comment: @ErnestoJrMontejo, you can also use do/end for enclosing the block instead of curly brackets. This allow to use a more complex logic (up to you) written on many lines.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution of iGian above is nice. But he introduced some new methods from new versions of Ruby. If you need a solution that can be used with lower versions too (and the new as well), then try this:

```
Proc.new { |arr| arr << arr.last + 1 }.call(Subject.pluck(:position))

# or

lambda { |arr| arr << arr.last + 1 }.call(Subject.pluck(:position))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome! the lambda method is the one I most like! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that I helped

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is the correct answer, or the right way to do what I wanted.

The codes where just complicated when in fact we can simply do like this…
In the form view:

```
<%= f.select :position, 1..@subject_count %>
```

Then in the controller:

```
@subject_count = Subject.count + 1
```

This generates the DB count + 1 without retrieving any duplicate (numbers)positions…
That's all! Quite amazing how simple it should be.